# Indexing to a specific core in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I stress that I am a complete newbie to Solr so go easy on me if the answer is glaringly obvious.

I have created two cores on Solr as some data I want to index are unrelated, I want to keep them separate. However, when I index the data, they always go into the first core 'collection1'. I want to be able to point these files to a certain core. How do I go about this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention the core name while indexing your document.

Say your cores are

1. collection1
2. collection2

While indexing to collection1 and collection2, your solr URL should be as follows

```
http://'localhost':4983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true
```

and

```
http://'localhost':4983/solr/collection2/update?commit=true
```